# How to build in button in Onsen sliding menu?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, menu, onsen-ui

Fow example, i have menu: http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/IDvFJ. How to add new element page3, so when user will hit it, he will activate code, like this:

```
Appmenu.onclick('page3', function(){
    alert("Hello");
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using AngularJS considering your tags.

Use `ngClick` directive:

```
<ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="someFunction()">
  Click me!
</ons-list-item>
```

And in your controller:

```
angular.module('appname').controller('SomeController', function($scope) {
  $scope.someFunction = function() {
    alert("Hello");
  }
});
```